# How to set Dashboard screen with drawer as initial root in Navigator in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer, navigator

I have set Initial root as `LoginScreen` in `Navigator` (component of react-native).
But after login I want `DashboardScreen` having drawer as initial root for navigation drawer present in `DashboardScreen`

In `App.js` for login initial root:

```
<Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{id: 'LoginScreen'}}
        renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}/>
```

In navigatorRenderScene() method, I have declared the different routes in app.
then how to add initial root as `DashboardScreen` after login success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state to declare a initial route.

```
if() //check if user if connected
        this.state.initial = {id: 'DashboardScreen'}
else
        this.state.initial = {id: 'LoginScreen'}
```

and in your Navigator:

```
<Navigator
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={this.state.initial}
        renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}/>
```